# Magento 2.3.4 issue "We can't save the customer"

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.4

I have migrated from 1.9.1 to 2.3.4. There is an issue while creating a customer account.

It says "We can't save the customer" as shown below screenshot. However, While checking on the database, an entry was there on the customer table.
[image]

Please, help to fix this issue.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

**Solution to Debug #1:**

- Remove all files under **[Document_Root]/var/log** directory.
- Retry customer registration.
- Check for the problems in the files under **[Document_Root]/var/log** directory.

**Solution to Debug #2:**

In **Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost::execute()** method, change the line:

```
$this->messageManager->addException($e, __('We can\'t save the customer.'));
```

to:

```
$this->messageManager->addException($e, $e->getMessage());
```

It will show the actual reason why the customer is not being saved.

Hope this helps.